# How do I aggregate data in sql for multiple rows of data by column name?

Tags: sql, count

hi im new to sql and trying to understand how to work with data structures. I have a table

```
 fact.userinteraction
interactionuserkey   visitdatecode 
0                    20220404      
1                    20220404      
5                    20220402
5                    20220128
```

If the interaction userkey number repeats then, i want a column called number of visits. in this case, for interactionuserkey 5, there are 2 total visits since its repeated twice. for interactionuserkey 0, number of visits =1 and so on. Basically, sum duplicates in column 1 and give total count AS number of visits. How do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sql, it's resolved using basic aggregation

```
select interactionuserkey, count(*)
from your_table
group by interactionuserkey
```

Comment: Thank you James. marked as correct.Im a rookie sql analyst. Literally my 2nd day on the job. if you feel my question would help the SO community in the future please upvote it or suggest ways i could improve the question. It would really help me. thank you

Comment: It's ok @JayJanardhan, I am happy to help and glad to help respectful people like you, unfortunatelly not that common. But this is quite sql basic, you can find tons of data googling. Just looking in youtube, you have this video of 8 hours. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AA7i2GcTGwU